# Multi module project: how to setup Dagger to provide interface but hide implementation-specific dependencies?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger, modularization, android-module

In my application, I have two modules: `app` and `repository`.
`repository` depends on Room, and has a `GoalRepository` interface:

```
interface GoalRepository
```

and a `GoalRepositoryImpl` class that is internal, as **I don't want to expose it or the Room dependency to other modules**:

```
@Singleton
internal class GoalRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(private val dao: GoalDao) : GoalRepository
```

`app` depends on `repository` to get a `GoalRepository` instance.
I have a `GoalRepositoryModule` that, at the moment, is:

```
@Module
class GoalRepositoryModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRepository(impl: GoalRepositoryImpl): GoalRepository = impl

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideGoalDao(appDatabase: AppDatabase): GoalDao = appDatabase.goalDao()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase =
        Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "inprogress-db").build()
}
```

The issue is that this won't compile (obviously) as the public `provideRepository` function is exposing `GoalRepositoryImpl`, that is an `internal` class.
How can I structure my Dagger setup to achieve what I want?

---

Edit:
I tried making `provideRepository` internal as per @David Medenjak comment and now the Kotlin compiler complains that it cannot resolve RoomDatabase dependency:

```
Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class xxx.repository.database.AppDatabase, unresolved supertypes: androidx.room.RoomDatabase
```

For completeness, the code of my Component inside the `app` module:

```
@Component(modules = [ContextModule::class, GoalRepositoryModule::class])
@Singleton
interface SingletonComponent
```

Comment: Why can't you make `provideRepository` internal as well? Just tried it, seems to work fine, especially since Dagger generates java code and internal is still "public" in Java

Comment: I tried your suggestion, now the Kotlin compiler complains about a missing dependency. I've updated my question

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the code Dagger was generating, I understood that the mistake was making the `@Component` inside the `app` module depend on the `@Module` inside the `repository` module.
So I made a separate `@Component` inside the `repository` module and made the `app` module's one depend on it.

### The code

The `repository` module's component:

```
@Component(modules = [GoalRepositoryModule::class])
interface RepositoryComponent {
    fun goalRepository(): GoalRepository
}
```

The `app`'s one:

```
@Component(modules = [ContextModule::class], dependencies = [RepositoryComponent::class])
@Singleton
interface SingletonComponent
```

This way the `RepositoryComponent` is responsible for building the `Repository` and knows all its dependencies, while the `SingletonComponent` only have to know about `RepositoryComponent`.

Comment: Can you provide the project's GitHub link? As I am trying to implement dagger 2 in a multi-module android project.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, and one think that makes me doubt is (I'm new to Dagger) .. that RepositoryComponent and the repository module itself, need Context to work, but that "dependence" is hidden so someone else will become aware of this when they compile the project and an error gets thrown. Is this a usual thing when using Dagger ?